# Magento2: Index page running problem (index source code displaying)

Tags: magento2.3, frontend, magento2.3.1, index, frontend-error

I have complete installation&run successfully magento2 package some days ago...

But, Now I trying to run the package

index.php source code was displaying while executing the magento2 package.

i try the URL 127.0.0.1/magento2_package/home ---> It's Correctly working,

And

Admin side URL 127.0.0.1/magento2_package/admin--->Correctly working,

This URL 127.0.0.1/magento2_package/  ---> It's shown the index.php source code.

[image]

Please give any solution or link for solve that issue...

Comment: I think permission issue

Comment: Thank you @JugalKishor

i try all command like(setup upgrade,static-content:deploy -f, indexer:reindex,cache:clean,And set the permission sudo chmod -R 777 ./)

now solved the issue ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue

Thorugh try all command like under root directory

(

sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade

sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

sudo bin/magento indexer:reindex

sudo php bin/magento cache:clean

sudo chmod -R 777 ./

)

solved this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your apache or nginx server is not configured properly, possisble caused of this issue is
1. Incorrect permissions
2. The nginx or apache server is not configured to identify *.php files
3. Also, check mod_rewrite it may not be configured.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible issue could be the missing modules. Try executing below (If your PHP version is 7.4)

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.4

sudo service apache2 restart
```